# Google script to copy one folder to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

We have a folder in a team drive that we need to copy to another folder in team drive. So when any changes happen in the 'master' folder it updates the slave folder. We are doing this so that if anything is accidentally deleted in the slave folder we wont lose anything. Can this be done?

Comment: Google has the vault and file change history. I don't think that you need a script to so this.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look